# Браузерная игра

Tags: разработка-игр

Сразу к делу. Есть одна игра. Хочу сам сделать такую же игру.  Не ругайте, я хотел добавить скрин игры, чтобы понятно было, о чем речь, но тут, оказывается, надо иметь 60 балов, у меня их нет, я зарегелся  для вопроса, поэтому дам название игры, чтобы было понятней, о чем речь (DarkSwords).

Вкратце о игре: мморпг, там есть чат и картинки, бои в автоматическом режиме, картинки меняются, чат ну и все, картинки и чат, например, ты ударил на 100 урона, тебе об этом в чате написалось тип такого.

В чем заключается просьба? 
По пунктам рассказать примерно что из себя игра представляет, типа:  на каком языке написана, какие языки были задействованы, чтоб получилась такая игра, в общем, примерно сказать,  что надо изучить\уметь, знать, чтобы я смог примерно сделать такую же игру. Хотя бы примерные ориентиры, что надо делать или знать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные игры делятся на три составляющие:

клиент <-> сервер <-> база данных

**Клиент**

На самом деле выбор тут не велик, у Вас два варианта:

- делать его на HTML+CSS + язык программирования JavaScript;
- делать его на Adobe Flash + язык программирования ActionScript.

В данном случае игра сделана по первому варианту.

**Сервер**

Вот тут интереснее, вариантов очень много и узнать, на чем сделана серверная часть затруднительно, так как она скрыта от посторонних глаз. Самым простым (но не самым лучшим) вариантом для изучения будет язык php, хотя лучше взять python для таких целей.

**База данных**

Соответственно, понадобится изучить Базы данных, какой-нибудь MySql или PostgreSql. Тут более важно понимать, как они строятся и знать язык запросов SQL. Обычно они изучаются после серверного языка или совместно с ним.

Ну и рассчитывать на то, что такую игру вы сможете сделать быстро, не стоит. Ориентировочно года на два-три тут хватит времени. ) Есть, правда, вариант взять еще конструктор какой-нибудь, но я не интересовался подобным.

Comment: Спасибо огромное тебе за ответ!  Очень помог!  Спасибо за то, что все так четко рассказал! Очень благодарен тебе. Удачи.